# Rounded corners for TABS in android

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs

I want to achieve rounded corners for the tab that I've constructed in my application. So far I was able to come up with this[image]

I would like my rounded corners to look as so. (I've coded it in such a way that only the right and left corners appear but when the states change it looks like the above image)
[image]

Below is the code that I've written so far. How can I achieve proper rounded corners  through code ?

SELECTED TAB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<corners
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>

<gradient
    android:startColor="#000" 
    android:endColor="#000"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:angle="-270"/>

</shape>
```

UNSELECTED TAB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<gradient 
android:angle="90" 
android:startColor="#880f0f10" 
android:centerColor="#8858585a" 
android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>

 <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

Thanks for your response !!  :)

Comment: May this article helpful to you somewhat: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

Comment: @Vinoth Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @Vinoth were you able to get a real solution for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use 4 shapes:

- for left button not selected
- for left button selected
- for right button not selected
- for right button selected

And then write selector to use for `button` background, see example for the left button (for the right just the similar):

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
  <gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:endColor="#000"
    android:gradientRadius="400"
    android:angle="-270"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#880f0f10"
        android:centerColor="#8858585a"
        android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>
   <corners
      android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
</item></selector>
```

Comment: how to add each tab with different selector ?

Answer (score 4):

**In java file, put this**

```
 tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedcorners);
```

**roundedcorners.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" 
       android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
       android:topRightRadius="5dp" />
 </shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Created alternate shapes to solve the problem

Note: These xml files are in addition to the two mentioned.

SELECTED TAB ALTERNATE.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle"
>
<corners
 android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
 android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>

<gradient
  android:startColor="#000" 
  android:endColor="#000"
  android:gradientRadius="400"
  android:angle="-270"/>

</shape>
```

UNSELECTED TAB ALTERNATE.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<gradient 
 android:angle="90" 
 android:startColor="#880f0f10" 
 android:centerColor="#8858585a" 
 android:endColor="#88a9a9a9"/>

 <corners
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"/>

</shape>
```

Afterwards, add this in your tab selection listener.

```
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            int selectedTabPosition = tab.getPosition();


            View firstTab = ((ViewGroup)    tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
            View secondTab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1);


            if (selectedTabPosition == 0)
            { // that means first tab
                firstTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_tab));
                secondTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_tab));


            } else if (selectedTabPosition == 1)
            { // that means it's a last tab

                firstTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_tab_alternate));
                secondTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.unselected_tab_alternate));


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who still looking for solution. This is what i done.Put tablayout inside MaterialCardView,

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"`enter code here`
            app:strokeColor="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp">
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
                app:tabTextColor="?attr/colorPrimary">
            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout> 
     </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**tabselector_backgroud.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_tab_selected" 
 android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_tab_unselected" 
  android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

**gradient_tab_selected.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="@color/lime"
    android:endColor="@color/lime"
    android:startColor="@color/lime"
    android:type="linear" />
 </shape>
```

**gradient_tab_unselected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"`enter code here`
        android:centerColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with one drawable for one view. For 2 tab need only 2 drawable. This will also worked for tabs with border color.

1. **For Left Tab:**

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <item android:state_selected="false">
       <layer-list >

         <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>

         </item>

         <item  android:right="-10dp">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>
         </item>

       </layer-list>
     </item>

     <item android:state_selected="true">
       <layer-list >

         <item >
           <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>

         </item>

         <item  android:right="-10dp">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />
               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>
         </item>

       </layer-list>

     </item>

   </selector>
   ```

**Left Tab Background Preview:**

[image: Left Tab Background Preview]

2. **For Right Tab:**

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:state_selected="false">
       <layer-list >
           <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>

           </item>

           <item  android:left="-10dp">
            <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            </shape>
           </item>

       </layer-list>

   </item>
   <item android:state_selected="true">
       <layer-list >
         <item >
           <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>

         </item>

         <item  android:left="-10dp">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />
               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>
         </item>

       </layer-list>

   </item>


   </selector>
   ```

**Right Tab Background Preview:**

[image]

3. **If there is more than 2 tabs Then this if for Middle Tab:**

   ```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="false">

     <layer-list >

       <item>
           <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>

       </item>

       <item  android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>
       </item>

     </layer-list>

    </item>
    <item android:state_selected="true">

      <layer-list >

       <item >
           <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>

       </item>

       <item  android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp">
           <shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
               <stroke
                   android:width="2dp"
                   android:color="@android:color/black" />
               <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
           </shape>
       </item>

      </layer-list>

    </item>

   </selector>
   ```

**Middle Tab Background Preview:**

[image]

Drawables have both selected and unselected state

Answer (score 0):

Another, completely different approach, might be to use a library like [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

Both libraries let you "program" your android in HTML5/CSS/Javascript.  Where "rounded tabs" abound.

Just a thought ...

Answer (score 0):

This code are for 2 tabs in tablayout:

One is selected and two is unselected mode

[image]

Drawable xml:

**When selecting Left tab:**

tabselectionleft:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"/>

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

notabselectionleft:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >

        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/colorAccent1" android:endColor="@color/colorAccent3"/>

            <corners android:topRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

**When selecting right tab:**

tabselectionright:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</shape>
```

notabselectionright:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:useLevel="true">


            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp" />
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/colorAccent3"
                android:startColor="@color/colorAccent1" />


        </shape>


    </item>
```

**In main layout tablayout decelartion**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent2"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="10dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    />
```

**Calling this drawable should happen programmatically as shown below:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_tabs);
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        firstTab = ((ViewGroup)    tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
        secondTab = ((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

        firstTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselectionleft));

        secondTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.notabselectionleft));



    }
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        int selectedTabPosition = tab.getPosition();

        if (selectedTabPosition == 0)
        { // that means first tab
            firstTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselectionleft));
                  secondTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.notabselectionleft));


        } else if (selectedTabPosition == 1)
        { // that means it's a last tab

            firstTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.notabselectionright));
            secondTab.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.tabselectionright));


        }
```