# How to create round corner tab in android like this?

Tags: android

is there any body know how to create a round corner tab like this:

Expected Tabs:
[image]

Coming Tabs:
[image]
hope you can tell me.Thank you.

Comment: use shape selector xml and set in banckground

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599755/rounded-corners-for-tabs-in-android

Comment: @Vinodh I used shape selector and the result like the coming tabs image show.But not the expected result.

Comment: @SatanPandeya Thanks for your answer.But it can not solve my problem.

Comment: @Fiend : Can you share the output of your code, a screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

@Vinodh I use Tablayout with ViewPager. I set a style to the Tablayout and set the tabBackground property with a selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape>
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#000"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

    </layer-list>


</item>
```

And set the background of Tablayout:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners android:topLeftRadius="8dp" android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
<solid android:color="#000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:radius="14dp"
/>
<gradient
android:angle="45"
android:centerX="35%"
android:centerColor="#000000"
android:startColor="#000000"
android:endColor="#000000"
android:type="linear"
/>
<padding
android:left="0dp"
android:top="0dp"
android:right="0dp"
android:bottom="0dp"
/>
<size
android:width="270dp"
android:height="60dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#000000"
/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to change tab layout make custom background in drawable and give rounded corner in both selected and selected tab**

[image: first tab selected]

[image: saved tab selected]

**In Your Activity/Fragment**
I set background in tablayout so you can make background as per your requirement

> adding only customization code for brevity

```
val tabCount: Int = images_videos_tab_layout.tabCount

    for (i in 0 until tabCount) {
        val tabView: View = (images_videos_tab_layout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(i)
        tabView.requestLayout()
        ViewCompat.setBackground(tabView,setImageButtonStateNew(requireContext()));
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(tabView, tabView.paddingStart, tabView.paddingTop, tabView.paddingEnd, tabView.paddingBottom);
    }

fun setImageButtonStateNew(mContext: Context): StateListDrawable {
    val states = StateListDrawable()
    states.addState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_normal_blue))
    states.addState(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_selected), ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.tab_bg_normal))

    return states
}
```

**In Drawable**

1.tab_bg_normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/your_unselected_tab_color" />
<corners android:radius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

2.tab_bg_normal_blue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/baseThemeColor" />
<corners android:radius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

3.tabview_bg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="25dp"/>
<stroke android:color="@color/baseThemeColor" android:width="1dp"/>
<solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```