# How to make each tab corner of Tablayout round shape in android?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, xml-drawable

I am using Tab Layout in my app.
Now what I want is to make each tab corner round shape.
So please help me to get rid of it.

Here I attached some screenshots.

**I have as below Image :**

[image: This is i have]

**I want as below Image:**

[image: This is i want]

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show us what code you have tried allready

Comment: @Modge this i the link which i am following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337754/android-tab-layout-tabs-with-round-corners

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599755/rounded-corners-for-tabs-in-android

Comment: @Ankita  Thanks..it's work like charm..cheers.

Comment: @vivekpagar Welcome. Then you can upvote me :P ;)

Comment: @Ankita....Sure

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use segment library to replace Tab Layout because it faster and customize simply

[android-segmented-control][1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create drawable for that and set it to your views refer to drawable below, copy into drawable file:

you can change radius value to change sharpness of corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="@color/primary" />

<padding
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

<corners android:radius="3dp" />
```

use `android:background="@drawablw/round_corner" attribute of your view to set that drawable`